# Magento 2 After Create New Admin User Role facing this error

Tags: magento2

Any one help me to fix this issue...?

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Acl_Role_Registry_Exception): Role '174' not found

Exception #0 (Zend_Acl_Role_Registry_Exception): Role '174' not found

```
#1 Zend_Acl->isAllowed(174, 'Bss_FacebookPixe...') called at [vendor/magento/module-authorization/Model/Acl/AclRetriever.php:120]
#2 Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\AclRetriever->getAllowedResourcesByRole(174) called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Block/Role/Tab/Edit.php:191]
#3 Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Edit->getSelectedResources() called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Block/Role/Tab/Edit.php:167]
#4 Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Edit->isEverythingAllowed() called at [vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/templates/role/edit.phtml:27]
#5 include('/mnt/singvoldill...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Edit#000000004d4ff5730000000004125d27#, '/mnt/singvoldill...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/mnt/singvoldill...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#9 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php:492]
#11 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(&Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Edit#000000004d4ff5730000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml:57]
#12 include('/mnt/singvoldill...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\User\Block\Role\Edit#000000004d4ff5770000000004125d27#, '/mnt/singvoldill...', array('tabs' => array('info' => &Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Info#000000004d4ff5480000000004125d27#, 'account' => &Magento\User\Block\Role\Tab\Edit#000000004d4ff5730000000004125d27#, 'roles' => &Magento\Framework\DataObject#000000004d4ff2f70000000004125d27#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/mnt/singvoldill...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#16 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('adminhtml.user.e...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.user.e...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.user.e...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('adminhtml.user.e...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('adminhtml.user.e...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:492]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004d4fdeb20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004d4fdeb20000000004125d27#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:193]
#62 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004d4fdeb20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:221]
#63 Magento\Framework\App\View->renderLayout() called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Role/EditRole.php:52]
#64 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Role/EditRole/Interceptor.php:24]
#65 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#66 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#67 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#68 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#69 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#70 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor#000000004d4fdd850000000004125d27#, &Closure#000000004d4fdd870000000004125d27#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#71 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#72 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Role/EditRole/Interceptor.php:39]
#73 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#74 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#, &Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Role\EditRole\Interceptor#000000004d4fdd850000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#75 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#76 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#77 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#78 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#79 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004d4fdef20000000004125d27#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#80 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#81 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#82 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000004d4fdebc0000000004125d27#) called at [index.php:76]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue is related to extension "Bss_FacebookPixel".

To test you can disable that extension and try again or you can select or deselect role related to this extension.

Comment: I already try this to remove this Plugin and then create again but next this next Module show Error... If i remove all module then its open